# Dual network configuration with NAS communication

Tags: networking, ip, router, nas, ubiquity

What network configuration would i need for this setup or is it even possible to set it up this way:

```
24 Port switch in Room1:
5x Production pc's - 192.168.2.20-99
1x NAS 192.168.2.100
1x Ubiquity AP Pro - 192.168.2.101
2x mini wifi pc's - 192.168.2.18-19


Fiber cable joining 2 switches using SFP+


24port switch in Room2:
WAN Internet In
somepc1 - 192.168.1.2
somepc2 - 192.168.1.3
somepc3 - 192.168.1.4
```

The Production PC's in room 1 AND all pc's in room 2 can talk with NAS

BUT
The Production PC's in room 1 AND all pc's in room 2 can NOT talk with each other

The Production PC's send packets to 255.255.255.255(cannot be changed) but the Room2 PC's CAN NOT receive them.

The Production PC's send packets to 255.255.255.255(cannot be changed) the Room1 PC's CAN NOT receive them.

Basically i want to keep the Production side of network clean from miscellaneous office packets and vice versa but still want NAS connectivity.
ps. I know this can be done using a VPN, im asking for a solution without one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest looking into Trunking (also known as 802.1Q) and VLANs. Trunking allows for VLANs to be extended to another switch. And VLANs, which are just virtual LANs can allow you to segment off your switch to keep individual groups of users/computers traffic separate. In theory, you should be able to put your different groups in different VLANs, and then setup trunking so the VLANs can be extended to both switches. this can only work if you have a managed switch.